# Partial Isometries: Characterization

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Given a C*-algebra $\mathcal{A}$

Consider an element:
$$J\in\mathcal{A}:\quad P:=J^*J$$

Then the equivalence holds:
$$JJ^*J=J\iff P^2=P=P^*$$

How can I prove this?

Comment: "This is not to gain reputation!!!"  But what *is* it for?  Why the interest in putting a standard textbook exercise into fake Q&A form on this website?

Comment: @JonasMeyer: "This is not to gain reputation" means please don't start voting down both question and answer just because it smells like generating reputation. Still if you don't like the question and or answer itself feel free to vote-down. *(Otherwise it really happens if I don't explain the possibility of Q&A on SE.)* My purpose is to simply have it mainly for myself and also for others available on here in SE. *(Apart from my clean notes on my notebook.)* Because the standard textbook check is operator-theoretic though it is an operator-algebraic problem.

Comment: Thank you.  I think you and I have different standard textbooks. The operator algebraic method is standard, too.  A suggestion: The disclaimer is an unnecessary distraction, and in particular it shows up first in search results, hiding the mathematical content.

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Good point, thanks! *(I moved it to the bottom.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: This proof works also for distinct Hilbert spaces!*

On the one hand:
$$P^2=J^*(JJ^*J)=J^*J=P$$
$$P^*=(J^*J)^*=J^*J=P$$

By the C*-property:
$$A\in\mathcal{A}:\quad A=0\iff A^*A=0$$

So on the other hand:
$$(JJ^*J-J)^*(JJ^*J-J)=P^3-P^2-P^2+P=0$$

Concluding the equivalence.